# SQL Update large table

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sql-update, bigdata

I have a question. I need to update two large table - `t_contact` (170 million rows) and `t_participants` (11 million rows). This tables both have column `CUSTOMER_ID`. Some of this IDs wrong and I need to update it. Wrong IDs is about 140 thousand.
I understand that if I will use `UPDATE TABLE` it takes a lot of times, but this two tables mustn't be unavailable for a long time. What should I do?

Comment: How can you know what is a wrong id?

Comment: A have a table t_wrong_ids which has two columns: OLD_ID, NEW_ID. OLD_ID - original right id, NEW_ID - wrong id which located in my big tables.

Comment: A typical approach would be to batch the updates, changing 100 or 1000 rows at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the wrong ID's stored some where you should use merge:

```
MERGE INTO t_contact D
USING (select * from t_wrong_ids) S
ON (D.CUSTOMER_ID = S.NEW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.CUSTOMER_ID = S.OLD_ID
```

A lot faster then a normal update.

Second table is the same:

```
MERGE INTO t_participants D
USING (select * from t_wrong_ids) S
ON (D.CUSTOMER_ID = S.NEW_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET D.CUSTOMER_ID = S.OLD_ID
```

Comment: But if t_contact has a 170 million rows...How long it will takes?

Comment: 170 mil records doesn't say much, depends on the data,columns ETC.. i can't really tell u.. What would you consider a good time? Anyways, It should be the fastest way

Comment: But if i make a copy of this table then update IDs and at last change this udpated table with original one? My original table t_contact really must be available almost always

Comment: Well, yes you can copy the table update it and then replace it with the old one. If looking at the update, merge is what you are looking for

Comment: Ok, how should i exchange this table. I understand that the first step will be: CREATE TEMP_T AS SELECT * FROM T_CONTACTS. Then a merge my temp table with t_wrong_ids but how exchange this temp table back?

Comment: Easily, rename the table to tmp and the tmp table to the original one. no need to exchange anything @Jdzel

Answer (score 1):

Split one of your tables to parts and process them one by one in PL/SQL block. For example, suppose, IDs are consequent, you take `t_participants` and split it to parts with 1 million rows in each:

```
begin
  -- 1 and 11 - hardcoded values, 
  -- since your t_participants table has 11 000 000 rows
  for i in 1..11 loop 
    merge t_contact c
    using (select * from t_participants 
           where id between (i - 1) * 1000000 and i * 1000000) p
       on (c.id = p.id)
     when matched then update ...;
  commit;
  end loop;
end;
```

I took size of a part 1000000 records, but you can choose another size. It will depend on your server performance. Try to update manually 100, 1000, 10000, etc. rows to define which size is most convenient.

Comment: That's unnecessary since he have table with the wrong id's

Comment: @sagi It's just general idea of update part by part. Link condition `on (c.id = p.id)` could be replaced with `on (c.correct_id = p.correct_id)` or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare
  i number := 0;
  cursor s1 is SELECT rowid, t.* FROM table_name  t WHERE column_name =x;
begin
  for c1 in s1 loop
      UPDATE table_name SET column_name = y
             where rowid = c1.rowid;
      i := i + 1;              -- Commit after every X records
      if i > 50000 then
         commit;
         i := 0;
      end if;
  end loop;
  commit;
end;
/
```